# Doing PUT using bash script

Tags: bash, rest, curl

I am writing a bash script that does this :

1. Get a list of customers
2. For each customer, query an API (get files) This returns id and name
3. For each file, do a PUT.

My question is, I want to both "id" and "name" in my PUT body, so how can I get this in a single loop on "files" API. I have written this:

```
URL="https://some-url.com"
API_TOKEN="some-token"


get_customers() {
    curl --insecure \
         --fail \
         --header "Accept: application/json" \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer ${API_TOKEN}" \
         -k ${URL}/api/org/customers
}

get_files() {
    curl --insecure \
         --fail \
         --header "Accept: application/json" \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer ${API_TOKEN}" \
         -k ${URL}/api/files/files
}

put_capability() {
    echo ""
    curl --insecure \
         --fail \
         --silent \
         --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer ${API_TOKEN}" \
         --data @- \
         ${URL}/api/files/files/{id}
    echo ""
}


customers=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
for customer_id in "${customers[@]}"; do
    fileshares=($(get_files ${customer_id} | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
    fileshares-names=($(get_files ${customer_id} | jq --raw-output '.values[].name'))
    for fileshare_id in "${fileshares[@]}"; do
        #call function put_capability and do subsequent PUT.
        #PUT needs two parameters, fileshares and fileshares-names
        
    done
done
```

Basically, I don't want to call "get_files" twice as I am doing now. I need both the "fileshares" and "fileshares-names" in my subsequent PUT API. Can this be done in one for loop on file shares?

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming you're asking me b/w JSON or XML. It supports JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse `get_files` output once by storing it in a temp file like that :

```sh
customers=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
for customer_id in "${customers[@]}"; do
    get_files ${customer_id} > /tmp/cust.txt
    fileshares=($(cat /tmp/cust.txt | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
    fileshares-names=($(cat /tmp/cust.txt | jq --raw-output '.values[].name'))
    for fileshare_id in "${fileshares[@]}"; do
        #call function put_capability and do subsequent PUT.
        #PUT needs two parameters, fileshares and fileshares-names
    done
done
```